# Error while running Calabash-android with a test app

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to set up Calabash-android to run with a test app but keep getting the following error.

I have generated keystore file in .android folder, but still getting the same error.

```
D:\Calabash>calabash-android resign EdgeConnectQA.apk
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:118:in ``': No such file or directory - "C:/Program Files (x86)/android-sdk_r10-windows/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/aapt" list "C:/Users/u46646/AppData/Local/Temp/d20161027-10688-1rl21xu/unsigned.apk" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:118:in `unsign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:111:in `block in resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:106:in `resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/bin/calabash-android:114:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'

D:\Calabash>
```

Comment: temp fix is copy the aapt latest from C:/Program Files (x86)/android-sdk_r10-windows/android-sdk-windows/build-tools/, under this folder go to latest version of build tool and copy the aapt to C:/Program Files (x86)/android-sdk_r10-windows/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/. but permanet fix you need to update the calabash latest version or 0.7 then try.

Comment: My Ruby version is 1.9.3. When I am trying to update my calabash-android to latest version I am getting another error related to luffa. Should I install a latest version of ruby?

Comment: oh, for calabash ruby version minimum should be 2 and above, please go through this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykZ3HIYOOnQ

Comment: Ok. I will install Ruby above 2 and try. Thank you.

Comment: I installed Ruby 2.2.3. And I tried to run dk.rb , I am getting the below things:

Comment: what you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your Calabash-Android version. 0.5.14 is very old.